# how to Filter on nested data in an Array using ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to filter an Array based on the user name and show It but when I try to filter it doesn't show any data.
User Structure Is like this

```
     buyer: [{
              address: ""
              contactNo: ""
              email: "test@gmail.com"
              name: "user"}]
    cutomerContact: "3058989778"
    orderDate: "2019-07-31T12:10:11.818Z"
    orderType: "general"
```

and my code to filter array is

```
this.userOrders = this.filteredOrders.filter(x => x.buyer = x.buyer.name == this.userName)
```

I have no Idea how to filter a nested data any Help would be appreciated

Comment: replace `this.filteredOrders.filter(x => x.buyer = x.buyer.name == this.userName)` with `this.filteredOrders.filter(x => x.buyer.name == this.userName)`

Comment: @Kinjal I have already tried this it gives nothing but an empty Array

Comment: if there will always be only one object inside buyer then you can try `this.filteredOrders.filter(x => x.buyer[0].name == this.userName)` else you have to loop over buyer inside filter

Answer (score 2):

User `filter` to filter the main array and `some function` to check the condition.

The some() method executes the function once for each element present in the array:

- If it finds an array element where the function returns a true value,
  some() returns true (and does not check the remaining values)
- Otherwise it returns false

```js
  name = 'user';
  
  filterData = [
                  {
                    "buyer": [
                      {
                        "address": "",
                        "contactNo": "",
                        "email": "user@gmail.com",
                        "name": "user"
                      }
                    ],
                    "cutomerContact": "3058989778",
                    "orderDate": "2019-07-31T12:10:11.818Z",
                    "orderType": "general"
                  },
                  {
                    "buyer": [
                      {
                        "address": "",
                        "contactNo": "",
                        "email": "test@gmail.com",
                        "name": "test"
                      }
                    ],
                    "cutomerContact": "3058989778",
                    "orderDate": "2019-07-31T12:10:11.818Z",
                    "orderType": "general"
                  }
                ]
                
                
  let result = this.filterData.filter( (x) => {
    return x.buyer.some(y => y.name == name)
  })
  
  console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

DEMO

```js
let testArray =  [
  {
    "name": "SO",
    "buyer": [
      {
        "address": "",
        "contactNo": "",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "name": "user"
      }
    ],
    "cutomerContact": "3058989778",
    "orderDate": "2019-07-31T12:10:11.818Z",
    "orderType": "general"
  }
];


let filteredArray = testArray.filter((element) => element.buyer.some((subElement) => subElement.name == 'user')); 
  
console.log(filteredArray);
```